# Using Yii's DatePicker Widget, how can I obtain the selected date to convert it to current week?

Tags: php, jquery, yii, datepicker

I've been trying to obtain the selected date on Yii's DatePicker widget  because I need to convert it to the year's week to which the selected date belongs. The first time I load the page, it properly displays the corresponding week according to the day (i.e. Today's october 15th, 2015 properly displays Week 42), but I can't figure out how to make it display the week of the new selected date.  I've tried 'submit' buttons and the onSelect function with no success. Thanks for your help.

Here is the widget's code.

```
    <?php $this->widget("zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker", array(
            "name"=>"reserva[fecha]",
            "attribute"=>"fecha",
            "model"=>$reserva,
            "value"=>$reserva->fecha,
            "language"=>"es",
            "options"=>array(
                'altField'=>'#some_selector',
                "dateFormat"=>"dd-mm-yy",
                'showButtonPanel'=>true,
                'changeYear'=>true,
                'changeMonth'=>true,
                'selectOtherMonths'=>true
                )
            )
    );
```

And here's the Date -> Week of the Year convert code.

```
            ddate = $reserva->fecha;
            $date = new DateTime($ddate);
            $week = $date->format("W");
            echo "Semana: $week";
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me when working with CJuiDatePicker

`$date = date('W',strtotime($ddate))`